# Linking project, where I use static member from other project

Tags: c++, static, linker

I have problem with linking, I have two project which compliles to two dlls ( A.dll B.dll ). In project A, i have static `Singleton singleton`.
Psudocode :
One of headers in project A

```
ClassA
...
...
Singleton singleton;
...
...
```

In some place in project B in cpp file i have:

```
...
...
ClassA::singleton.SomeMethod();
...
...
```

Project compile, but there is a problem with linking.

I have this problem in **FreeCryEngine SDK**
This happen when I try to invoke `CCryAction::GetCryAction()` in GameDLL Project.
This don't work:

```
int a = CCryAction::GetCryAction()->IsInLevelLoad();
```

> Error 3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static
>   class CCryAction * CCryAction::m_pThis"
>   (?m_pThis@CCryAction@@0PAV1@A)    E:\CryENGINE_v3_3_5_2456_FreeSDK\Code\Game\GameDll\GameStateRecorder.obj    GameDll

How this method look ?

```
static CCryAction * GetCryAction() { return m_pThis; }
```

Comment: You have let us know what error you have, how you are linking at the moment, or just ask how to link a simplified but similarly structured solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need: in the header

```
struct ClassA {
    static Singleton singleton;
};

// or  
extern Singleton g_singleton;
```

In cpp file:

```
Singleton ClassA::singleton;

// or
Singleton g_singleton;
```

So you can call `ClassA::singleton.someMethod()` or `::g_singleton.someMethod()` in *translation units* that include the header. Be sure to link the object file for the cpp above.